# iAd error: setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key adView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iad, adbannerview

I'm after some help understanding why I am getting this error when attempting to run a test app with just an iAd banner:

```
iAdTest[12856:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
 reason: '[<KAMViewController 0xa239f50> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key 
value coding-compliant for the key adView.'
*** First throw call stack:
```

my code is:

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <iAd/iAd.h>
@interface KAMViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet ADBannerView *bannerAd;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL bannerIsVisible;
@end
```

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
_bannerAd = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
_bannerAd.frame = CGRectOffset(_bannerAd.frame, 0, -50);
[_bannerAd setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
[self.view addSubview:_bannerAd];
_bannerAd.delegate = self;
self.bannerIsVisible = NO;
[super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
if (!self.bannerIsVisible) {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
    banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, 50);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    self.bannerIsVisible = YES;
}
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
if (self.bannerIsVisible) {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
    banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -50);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    self.bannerIsVisible = NO;
}
}
```

The single view storyboard (XCode 5.0) has just the ADBannerView applied as this is meant as a simple test program to understand how to implement an iAd & ensure it rotates with orientation changes etc.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I'm trying to piece this together using the iAd guide & google - but I don't get where 'bannerView' comes from in here???:

```
(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{

if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation))
    self.bannerView.currentContentSizeIdentifier =
        ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape;
else
    self.bannerView.currentContentSizeIdentifier =
}
ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
```

Comment: So where do you use `adView`? In the storyboard as an outlet?

Comment: i am not using adView - I thought that adView was just a property/variable name like 'bannerAd' in my code?